# Python widget layout without modifying original code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, vbox, hbox

I have the following original code where all widgets are displayed along one column only and I would like to display them along 2 columns.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Button, HBox, VBox

dW = widgets.Dropdown(options=['2', '1'])
rW = widgets.FloatText(200)
aW = widgets.FloatText(1)


@interact(D=dW, R=rW, A=aW)

def print_p(D, R, A):
    dW = D
    rW = R 
    aW = A
```

I have read the docs and it suggests to use the following format:

```
left_box = VBox([dW, rW])
right_box = VBox([aW])
HBox([left_box, right_box])
```

Is there a way to integrate the code above so I do not need to change the original format and see the 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual, Text
import ipywidgets as widgets

dW = widgets.Dropdown(options=['2', '3'])
rW = widgets.FloatText(200)
mW = widgets.FloatText()          

left_box = VBox([dW, rW])
right_box = VBox([mW])
ui = HBox([left_box, right_box])

def print_p(Provvigione_Agente_EUR, R, M):
    dW = Provvigione_Agente_EUR
    rW = R
    mW.value = int(dW)*int(rW)

    
out = widgets.interactive_output(print_p, {'Provvigione_Agente_EUR':dW, 'R':rW, 'M':mW})

display(ui, out)
```